# Count of all possible combinations from multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have the lists:

```
list_a = set(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"])
list_b = set(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"])
list_c = set(["red", "yellow", "blue", "green"])
```

I would like to find the **total number of possible combinations** of these lists (one item per lists)

This is easily possible with smaller lists

```
import itertools as it

list_set = [list_a, list_b, list_c] 

len(list(it.product(*list_of_unq_vars)))
```

Which will return the number of combinations.

However for larger lists i run into a memeory error.

Is there a way to calculate the number of possible combinations in this manner without actually creating the combinations themselves (as i have done above)?

Many thanks,
J

Comment: `len(list_a) * len(list_b) * len(list_c)`?

Comment: multiply the number of all items of each list with each other (like @meowgoesthedog pointed out)

Comment: doesn't @meowgoesthedog solves your issue, you mean something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is multiply the length of each list to get total number of combinations possible:

```
tempcomb = 1
for l in list_set:
    tempcomb *= len(l)
print(tempcomb)
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific with your answer (explain why, what, edit code to actually look like code...)

Comment: I dun hit enter too fast...

Comment: right, looking good now ;)